# Can a logstash filter error be forwarded to elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm having these json parsing errors from time to time:

```
2022-01-07T12:15:19,872][WARN ][logstash.filters.json    ] Error parsing json
 {:source=>"message", :raw=>" { the invalid json }", :exception=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unrecognized character escape 'x' (code 120)
```

Is there a way to get the **:exception** field in the logstash config file?

Answer (score 0):

I opened the exact same thread on the [elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-a-logstash-filter-error-be-forwarded-to-elastic/293742) and got a working solution there. Thanks to @Badger on the forum, I ended up using the following raw ruby filter:

```
   ruby {
        code => '
            @source = "message"
            source = event.get(@source)
            return unless source

            begin
                parsed = LogStash::Json.load(source)
            rescue => e
                event.set("jsonException", e.to_s)
                return
            end

            @target = "jsonData"
            if @target
                event.set(@target, parsed)
            end
        '
    }
```

which extracts the info I needed:

```
"jsonException" => "Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{ \"baz\", \"oh!\" }\r\"; line: 1, column: 9]",
```

Or as the author of the solution suggested, get rid of the **@target** part and use the normal json filter for the rest of the data.